# "Attaboy!" variations

Tags: usage, phrase

What exclamation words or phrases would you say to a man who had just done a good job (or maybe ironically)? I am interested both in formal and colloquial ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are all kinds of things you could say. Starting with a simple

> "Gut!"

, or stronger

> "Sehr gut"
>   "Exzellent"
>   "Perfekt"
>   "Großartig"

or, more colloquial:

> "super"
>   "klasse"
>   "spitze"

Closer to your "*attaboy*" should be

> "Guter Mann!"
>   "Gut/ Klasse/ Prima/ Exzellent/ Hervorragend/ Großartig/ ...   gemacht!"
>    "Gute / Klasse/ Prima / ... Arbeit!"

Writing this i must admit i am a bit surprised how many different ways of stating that someone did something in a commendable manner we have... :-)

Comment: Good answer, but could you please add a little more structure and formatting?

Comment: @dervonnebenaan If you have suggestions how to format that better, feel free to edit my answer!